# How can I debug a "missing" hp raid card?

Tags: hp-proliant, hardware-raid

I have a DL380G6 running great with a P800 and P410i, but I wanted to upgrade the P800 to a P812. I now have both controllers plugged in. In the BIOS I have the option of selecting the 410i or the 800 but not the 812. In the POST process, the 410i initializes as well as the 800 but no mention of the 812.

Once I get booted this is the output of `lspci`:

```
root@bacon:~# lspci | grep Hew
01:04.4 USB controller: Hewlett-Packard Company Integrated Lights-Out Standard Virtual USB Controller
01:04.6 IPMI SMIC interface: Hewlett-Packard Company Integrated Lights-Out Standard KCS Interface
04:00.0 RAID bus controller: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array G6 controllers (rev 01)
07:00.0 RAID bus controller: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array Controller (rev 04)
```

Shouldn't I see another HP raid card (I assume the "G6 controllers" item is the 410i)?

I've also run the firmware upgrade utility but it doesn't find anything that needs to be upgraded. How else can I see if the card is bad or is just not being detected?

I can see some lights on the 812, but sadly they're on the top of the card, which becomes the bottom when placed in the cage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troubleshooting it...

If the card isn't present at [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test), then there's likely a problem with the device.

- Did you try the card in a different server? If not, try checking that.
- Did you try the Smart Array P812 in a different PCIe slot? If not, please try that.

Where did you get the controller from? Do you have any recourse with the vendor if it *is* bad?

Comment: I'll be contacting the vendor on Monday, I just wanted to make sure I'd exercised all of my options and it seemed that something is very wrong since it didn't POST. I've since tried the card in another server (and had already tried it in a different slot). Thanks.